# What is the definition of $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0)$ uniformly w.r.t x?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

What is the definition of $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0)$ uniformly w.r.t x ?

I know uniform convergence of sequences of functions. Does it have anything to do with that?

**Is it possible that it is supposed to mean something like the following:**

*Let $\{h_{n}\}_{n}$ be a sequence s.t. $h_{n}\to 0$, then the sequence of functions defined by $\{f_{n}(x):=f(x,h_{n})\}_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f(x,0)$?*

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Should $t$ be $x$? Otherwise I think it's meaningless.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: If you don't want to go all the way down to $\epsilon$-$\delta$, you can write the definition as $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left( \sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}}|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|\right)=0$. Taking the supremum over $x$ is what we mean by "uniformly over $x$". This is of course equivalent to requiring that for every sequence $\{h_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $0$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}}|f(x,h_n)-f(x,0)|\right)=0$.

Comment: Does this mean that $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0)$, for all $x\in D$. In other words it is independant of x? In case one can say this I would get something like: $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0),\forall x\in D\iff \lim_{h\to 0 \sup_{x\in D}}|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|=0$, which I would show as follos:
Suppose $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0),\forall x\in D$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider $\tilde{\epsilon}:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. We can find $\delta>0$ s.t. $|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|<\tilde{\epsilon}:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now consider $\{|f(x,h)-f(x,0)| :x\in D\}$.

Comment: Then, if $|h|<\delta$, we have that $|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|<\tilde{\epsilon}:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thus $\sup\{|f(x,h)-f(x,0)| :x\in D\}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$. Hence, $\lim_{h\to 0}\sup\{|f(x,h)-f(x,0)| :x\in D\}=0$. (I consider $\sup\{|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|:x\in D\}$ to be a function of h.)

Comment: Now suppose $\lim_{h\to 0}\sup\{|f(x,h)-f(x,0)| :x\in D\}=0$, then for $\delta>0$ it follows that $\epsilon>|\sup_{x\in D}(|f(x,h)-f(x,0)|)|\geq |f(x,h)-f(x,0)|)|$. Hence, $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=f(x,0),\forall x\in D$. 

I hope it makes sense.@peek-a-boo

Answer (score 1):

It means that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such
that
$$
\left|f(x,h)-f(x,0)\right|<\varepsilon
$$
whenever $x\in X$ and $0<|h|<\delta$. Note that $\delta$ does not
depend on $x$ but depends on $\varepsilon$ only.

For pointwise convergence $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}f(x,h)=f(x,0)$, it
means that for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X$, there exists $\delta>0$
(usually depends on $\varepsilon$ and $x$) such that $\left|f(x,h)-f(x,0)\right|<\varepsilon$
whenever $0<|h|<\delta$.

Comment: Isn't that uniform continuity?

Comment: No. Uniform continuity is something about $x$. Here, we do not compare $f(x,h)$ and $f(y,h)$ when $y$ is close to $x$. So, continuity (in the first variable) is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay.Is it uniformly continous in h by any chance?

Comment: @Hans I think it's nothing to do with uniform continuity because it tells about the behavior of $f$ around the single point where $ h = 0$.